# Will Metal work on non A7 devices? (for example iPhone 5 or iPad Mini (not retina))

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, metal

Will Metal work on non A7 devices? (for example iPhone 5 or iPad Mini (not retina)). If not, is any way to create application for Metal supported devices only?

Answer (score 4):

It is for A7 or greater. The WWDC videos say "Designed for A7" and they kept emphasizing that throughout the presentations.

Comment: Designed for A7 does't mean designed only for A7.

Comment: according to the sample code the requirements are 64bit and iOS 8 "MetalDeferredLighting

Last Revision: 
Version 1.0, 2014-06-05
New sample code that demonstrates a deferred lighting algorithm using Metal. 
Build Requirements: 
iOS 8 SDK
Runtime Requirements: 
iOS 8 and 64bit processor"

Comment: From dev forums Filip Iliescu an Apple Employee says "Metal is only supported on A7 devices. OpenGL ES 3 is also only supported on A7 devices and practically speaking anything you could do there you can also do in Metal."

Answer (score 1):

Based on prior experience with frameworks I believe it would actually be based on iOS version and not processor, but Metal could be an exception. Apple does say "Metal provides extremely low-overhead access to the A7 GPU" in documentation making me believe it only works with A7.

Comment: Yes, I am already read this. But any information about A7 only and one more in case id metal work only on A7 devices we should have capability to restrict other devices or write additional code for support devices without metal (for example using openGL)

Comment: Could you rephrase that?

Comment: I mean that there is no any information that metal is supported **only** by A7+ devices. But if only for A7 devices, this is mean that we should have _device capability_ to restrict application from installation in not A7 devices, or if no _capability_ we should write code to support non A7 devices.

Comment: Maybe that feature will come in a new Xcode beta or something

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. There is **metal** capability in device capabilities (in plist).

Answer (score 0):

It's based on processor: it needs 64-bit gpu.  I set my builds to arm64.
Metal is apple's implementation of OpenGL 3 supposedly without all of the "crud from 20 years of software dev" so the video says.